# REST API Custom Response query

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

I am a bit new to REST API. I have the below controller created to mock an API Service called by a client code under Test. I need to return the response in JSON format as mentioned in the query and need some help to fix it.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ApiKeyAuth]
    [ValidateModel]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Item), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewItem([FromBody] Item item)
    {

        var itemId = await _repo.AddItemAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItemById), new { itemId, controller = "Example" },
            itemId);
    }
```

Contract:

```
public interface IExampleControllerRepository
{
    Task<int> AddItemAsync(Item item);
}
```

Repo:

```
public class ExampleRepository : IExampleControllerRepository
{
    private readonly ExampleDbContext _context;

    public ExampleRepository(ExampleDbContext context) => _context = context;

    public async Task<int> AddItemAsync(Item item)
    {
        _context.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return item.ItemId;
    }

}
```

Expected positive response template:

```
{"response":{"status":0,"data":[{"id":"1234"}]}}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! First off great job on asking your first question. Can you look into how to highlight your code, this will help improve the quality of your question. Here's a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult object that produces
        //     a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status201Created response.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   actionName:
        //     The name of the action to use for generating the URL.
        //
        //   routeValues:
        //     The route data to use for generating the URL.
        //
        //   value:
        //     The content value to format in the entity body.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual CreatedAtActionResult CreatedAtAction(string? actionName, object? routeValues, [ActionResultObjectValue] object? value)
    {
         throw null;
    }
```

The response body's template is related to the type of `value`, So if you want to get the response template like:

```
{"response":{"status":0,"data":[{"id":"1234"}]}}
```

You need to pass a `value` of a specific type instead of `itemId`.

Here is a simple demo.

```
public class Test
    {
        public List<response> responses { get; set; }
    }

public class response
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<test1> data { get; set; }
    }

public class test1
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**For testing convenience, I just hard code here.**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ApiKeyAuth]
        [ValidateModel]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Item), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewItem([FromBody] Item item)
        {
            Test test = new Test()
            {
                responses = new List<response>()
                {
                    new response()
                    {
                        status = 0,
                        data = new List<test1> { 
                              new test1()
                              {
                                  Id = "1234",
                              }
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            var itemId = await _repo.AddItemAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItemById), new { Id = item.ItemId }, test);
        }
```

**Result**

[image]